# How can get Command Event id with ShowTaskPane in Office JS Excel add-in

Tags: excel, office-js

We are using Custom Tab in Manifest file for Excel add-in. We were able to get ribbon command event id when Action type is "Execute-function". But how can we get the same when Action type is "ShowTaskPane". Kindly advise.

Hi  team any suggestion?

Comment: Hi Team,  Any  idea on this request?

Comment: Hi Team, Hope Keyur patel suggested to team to have look at this request.... Kindly help ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible. Due to "ExecuteFunction" action requiring a callback function, you are able to fetch the event ID within the callback function. However, a "ShowTaskPane" action does not require a callback function hence there is no opportunity for the add-in runtime to determine the event ID.

To emphasize this suggestion, please vote/suggest at [Office Developer Voice](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/).